# Print json data using MatTableModule

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular-material

so I have a springboot server exposing json data to my angular app, the data structure is `IBatchInstance` linked below.

The json GET request goes well but the DATA does not print, I think I did an error when trying to access to the `batchDef` properties inside my `batchInstance` object, but as a angular beginner I don't know how to correct it.
Any ideas?

PrintJsonComponent.ts

```
export class PrintJsonComponent implements OnInit {

    displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'label', 'perimeter', 'batchState',
                        'creationDate', 'lastModifiedDate'];        
    receivedBatchesData: IBatchInstance[];
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.receivedBatchesData);


constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.makeRequest();
}

makeRequest(): void {
    this.http.get<IBatchInstance[]>(myDataURL).subscribe(data => {
        this.receivedBatchesData = data;
    },
    err => {
        console.log('An error occured during the http GET request');
    });
}
```

dataJson.ts :

```
 export interface IBatchInstance {
    id: number;
    batchDef: IBatchDef;
    batchState: string;
    inputData: any[];
    outputData: any[];
    creationDate: string;
    lastModifiedDate: string;
    username: string;
  }

  export interface IBatchDef {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    launchCommand: string;
    perimeter: string;
    inputDataDefs: any[];
    outputDataDefs: any[];
  }
```

PrintJsonComponent.html :

```
<!-- ID Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.id}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.batchDef.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Label Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="label">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Label </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.batchDef.label}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Perimeter Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="perimeter">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Perimeter </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.batchDef.perimeter}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- batchState Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="batchState">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Batch state </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.batchState}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- creationDate Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="creationDate">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Creation date </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.creationDate}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- lastModifiedDate Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="lastModifiedDate">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last modification </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let batchInstance"> {{batchInstance.lastModifiedDate}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `this.receivedBatchesData = data;` and what you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

Ok my mistake was on dataSource object, here the correction to make it works :

```
     dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
     makeRequest(): void {
            this.http.get<IBatchInstance[]>(testJsonBatchesDr3).subscribe(data => {
                this.dataSource.data = data;
                console.log(this.dataSource.data);
            },
            err => {
                console.log('An error occured during the http GET request');
            });
        }
```